# convert dataframe to be returned as "application-json" in flask python

Tags: python, pandas

```
  dfList = df.values.tolist()
  return jsonify(dfList)
```

I have this as result, it's actualy removing the variable names of the DataFrame and replacing them with integers

```
-0: [
  0: "Les abeilles sont dehors",
  1: "ObservationNature",
  2:  0.6790075732725341,
  3:  [],
],
-1:[
  0: "elle sont allée chercher le miel à coté des fleurs du rucher",
  1: "ObservationNature",
  2: 0.4250480624587389,
  3: [],
]
```

my result should look like this, with the varibales that are in the DataFrame

```
-0: [
  "texte": "Les abeilles sont dehors",
  "type": "ObservationNature",
  "nluScore":  0.6790075732725341,
  "ruche":  [],
],
-1:[
  "texte": "elle sont allée chercher le miel à coté des fleurs du rucher",
  "type": "ObservationNature",
  "nluScore": 0.4250480624587389,
  "ruche": [],
],
```

Answer (score 14):

Use `df.to_json()` and set `mimetype='application/json'`

for example:

```
from flask import Response
@app.route("/dfjson")
def dfjson():
    """
    return a json representation of the dataframe
    """
    df = get_dataframe_from_somewhere()
    return Response(df.to_json(orient="records"), mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: great answer! for a different structure of the json, refer to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: Make sure to replace NaN values before exporting to json, for example using `np.nan_to_num`

Answer (score 6):

That's because you're passing ndarray type to jsonify.

Although df.to_json(orient="records") will serve you right, 
you can achieve your specific format through df.iterrows() and/or defaultdit
Here is an example:

```
@app.route('/')
def pandasJSON():
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': 1.,
                        'C': pd.Series(1, index=list(range(4)), dtype='float32'),
                        'D': np.array([3] * 4, dtype='int32'),
                        'E': pd.Categorical(["test", "train", "test", "train"]),                    
                        'F': 'foo'})

    df2['G'] = [100,200,300,400]
    df2.set_index('G', inplace=True)
    result = {}
    for index, row in df2.iterrows():
        #result[index] = row.to_json() 
        result[index] = dict(row)
    return jsonify(result)
```

[image: Output Image]

Answer (score 2):

Look in [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

```
df.to_json(orient='records')
'[{"col 1":"a","col 2":"b"},{"col 1":"c","col 2":"d"}]'
```

Encoding/decoding a Dataframe using 'index' formatted JSON:

```
df.to_json(orient='index')
'{"row 1":{"col 1":"a","col 2":"b"},"row 2":{"col 1":"c","col 2":"d"}}'
```

Encoding/decoding a Dataframe using 'columns' formatted JSON:

```
df.to_json(orient='columns')
'{"col 1":{"row 1":"a","row 2":"c"},"col 2":{"row 1":"b","row 2":"d"}}'
```

Encoding/decoding a Dataframe using 'values' formatted JSON:

```
df.to_json(orient='values')
'[["a","b"],["c","d"]]'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run

```
df.to_json(orient="records")
```

it should provide you with the output that you want (note: as of Pandas version 0.23.3)

Answer (score 0):

transform `df` to dictionary: `jsonify(df.to_dict())`

see below:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/dfjson")
def dfjson():
    """
    return a json representation of the dataframe
    """
    return jsonify(df.to_dict())
```

see [Doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) for different configurations